# Checking specific value in node in XML 1.0 not working

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get a specific value that is in my XML file and change the text if it matches by using when test.

The problem is that it does not get it, actually.

**The XSL:**

```
<xsl:template match="/root/system/coolname">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".='coolynamey'">
        <xsl:text>Male</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:text>Female</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

**The XML:**

```
<root>
  <system>
     <coolname>coolynamey</coolname>
  </system>
</root>
```

So what I want: *if the node contains coolynamey, than change it to Male. If not, make it female.* What it does now is that it outputs 'female', instead of male, even if 'coolynamey' exists.

Comment: Works for me. I cannot reproduce your finding with Saxon 6.5.5

Comment: Can you show the *actual* XML input you are using? The one you have there has no `coolynamey` nodes. Perhaps you are transforming the wrong source?

Comment: Hmm. Does not work for me. Thanks anyway, mister Müller.

Comment: @helderdarocha it changed to 0.0 by itself, odd, but anyhow, I edited it. This is the true source.

Comment: If it doesn't work, the problem may be caused by other templates. Post your full XSLT stylesheet.

Comment: Could it be because I am using a `call-template` in a for-each?

Comment: Please always post a _complete_ XSLT stylesheet. Otherwise it is impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Siyah, can this question be closed? It looks like it was identified as unreproducible, and no updates were made after this (e.g. the addition of a stylesheet).

Answer (score 2):

> Hmm. Does not work for me. Thanks anyway, mister Müller.

Well, this is a trivial transformation and I am sure it works.

**Input 1**

```
<root>
  <system>
     <coolname>coolynamey</coolname>
  </system>
</root>
```

**Input 2**

```
<root>
  <system>
    <coolname>somethingelse</coolname>
</system>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root/system/coolname">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test=".='coolynamey'">
            <xsl:text>Male</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:text>Female</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Output 1**

```
Male
```

**Output 2**

```
Female
```